# An insensible hexagon

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, mazes, seasonal

[image]

The puzzle is (almost) self-contained in the grid above. You can "move" from a tile of the grid to another if they share at least a vertex. After the maze is complete six things will clue to the solution which is an English phrase composed of four words of lenght 3,7, 7 and 10 letters.

EDIT: I've updated the picture due to an error (call it a typo). This edit does not impact the method that should be used to find the solution, the solution itself changes only a little bit.
Pleas don't look at the edit history if you want to solve this puzzle from scratch, otherwise it will be too simple.

Comment: Oh my god that looks scary

Comment: Now there's a spot near the bottom where a "w" doesn't connect to an "x".

Comment: @aschepler I must have inverted a 'w' with a 'v'. Sorry about that I was in a rush because I had to correct the typo

Comment: @aschepler fixed now. Sorry about that again again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on msh210's excellent answer, here's my conclusion:

> The only remaining letters in the maze that aren't Mike Shinoda's tweet or strings of a-z seem to be "*rip CCB*" (they're near '...true. An...'). And since we already know the riddle is about Chester Bennington's death (and was posted on the 3rd anniversary of it), the fitting phrase for the 3,7,7,10 grid that the riddle seems to indicate would be:
>
>  **RIP Chester Charles Bennington**

Comment: This would explain why (po orpnzr ppo va gur svkrq evqqyr - naq gur tevq gura tnvarq n frira).

Comment: that's correct, I had to fix the grid somehow

Answer (score 14):

> The path is
>
> [image]

which spells out

> "Shocked and heartbroken, but it's true.  An official statement will come out as soon as we have one." (except in lowercase and with neither punctuation nor spaces). That's [Mike Shinoda's tweet about Chester Bennington's death](https://twitter.com/mikeshinoda/status/888112045190561793). The path goes from **"LK" in** to a **park** because both men were members of the music band Linkin Park. The shape the path takes is the Linkin Park logo. The title of this puzzle may be a reference to the death as insensible (in the sense of "meaningless") or to the Linkin Park song "Numb" (which means insensible in its more usual meaning), besides of course referring to what appears to be a meaningless grid of letters. The leftover letters (unused in the path) go through the alphabet repeatedly and connectedly except for two stray letters *C* and *B* (the only capital letters in the grid) for Bennington's initials. As for "the solution which is an English phrase composed of three words of lenght 3,7 and 10 letters" (sic), I really don't know, but can guess that it's "bye, Chester Bennington". (This is a solution to the puzzle as originally posted. It was modified after this answer was posted.)

Comment: That was too fast! You got almost all the job done by finding 4 clues out of 6. Please refer to the updated image to find the solution (English phrase composed of four words of lenght 3,7, 7 and 10 letters)

Comment: Can you please find the cure for Covid19 now... Humanity needs you

Comment: There are three other unused letters.  (in your original solution)

Comment: I feel like (gur rknpg cbfvgvba bs gur gjb neebjf vf fhccbfrq gb fcryy bhg Y-va-X-va).

Comment: @walt that's correct. I couldn't resist making this pun